# What is the behaviour of a = b when a and b are unions?

Tags: c++, c, unions

As far as I understand the C and C++ standard regarding unions, it is technically undefined behaviour if I try to access a particular field of a union that is different to the field that was actually written to. Recently I have been reviewing some old code written by someone else that is similar to the following:

```
 union myunion {
     float myfloat;
     unsigned int myuint;
 };

 myunion a;
 a.myfloat = 1.01;

 myunion b = a;
```

in a nutshell, I am trying to find out if using the assignment operator on a union in this way is actually well defined behaviour. When I write code like this myself, I endeavour to store the type of the field actively used by a union instance and make sure that I only read or write this value. I am guessing that using the assignment operator above perhaps just results in a bitwise copy (since in this example the fields are of equal size) as stepping through the code in the debugger shows that this is what is happening. This code has been exhibiting subtle bugs so I am keen to find out if there is anything inherently risky in the sense of UB by directly assigning a union to another in this way.

Comment: You have answered it yourself. : ) Union assignment will result in a bitwise copy.

Comment: Even if the sizes of the elements aren't equal, the bitwise copy will work if all of the members are PODs.  (Which used to be required.)

Comment: I believe there are some special rules when a union or struct contains unnamed members? If someone could clarify what happens with such members, that would be great. Also, what happens with padding bytes?

Comment: “it is technically undefined behaviour if I try to access a particular field of a union that is different to the field that was actually written to” Footnote 82 in C99TC3 is a little more forgiving than that.

Comment: @PascalCuoq by "access" it only means you are trying to READ the value that was not set. You can safely WRITE to a different member.

Comment: @CashCow That seems to me to be the same meaning of “access” (for reading) that is used in C99TC3 footnote 82.

Comment: @Jay: Union assignment is not specified to result in a bitwise copy.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Indeed, but most of the time (except when the compiler can determine statically the most recently written member), full bitwise copy is the only way it can be implemented that satisfies the other requirements of the standard.

Comment: @R.: That is terrific information for anybody who likes writing code that works “most of the time” and fails obscurely in some circumstance months or years after it was originally written. No point in using a specification to construct good code when you can drive people nuts, decrease software reliability, and increase costs, eh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pre-C++11, `union` could only contain PODs (or something similar)—the restrictions were so designed that a bitwise copy would work.  In C++11, some of the restrictions have been lifted, but if you violate the old restrictions, copy and assignment are deleted (unless you define the operators yourself).

Answer (score 2):

As you would expect it to be. The behaviuor is well-defined.

b now has the same value as a, myfloat valued 1.01. Assignment is bitwise. If you want to compare a and b in a "safe" way you could do a bitwise comparison. (Using `operator==` on the float member isn't quite as safe, partly because it's UB if one of them doesn't actually contain a float, and partly of the issues of comparing floating point). Comparing for equality isn't actually automatically defined for unions so you would have to write an overload.

Unions always have only raw types in them that allow assignment to work. The only issue can be if the type can be a pointer and you manage that pointer somewhere. Then if you have two instances of your union holding this pointer you have to be careful. (However this would apply too if you even have a regular variable that contains a pointer).

Comment: With unions, when you do a=b; then after (a==b) you can never guarantee your result to be true. That's depend on the compiler you are using. Possible padding bytes inserted into your union may be handled differently by the comparisons operators of compilers.

Comment: There is "no general issue comparing floating point values". Floats have a perfectly well-defined order. Either a<b, a==b or a>b, the result is deterministic, and after an assignment both values are _exactly_ equal. You might have been confused by certain imprecise floating point operations such as 1.0/3.0, which is entirely distinct from comparison.

Comment: @StephaneD There is no automatic operator== for unions but for C++ you could write an overload. unions themselves don't hold which particular member is set, so if the two unions are not holding the same data type they are undefined.

Comment: @MSalters: Only the numerical values of floats (including infinities) are well ordered. Comparisons to NaNs return false, even when a NaN is compared for equality to itself. But this is a separate issue from whether any floating-point error is introduced by copying a union.

Comment: @CashCow: There are **no** issues comparing floating point numbers that would affect the comparison of `b.myfloat == a.myfloat` after `b = a`. If `a.myfloat` contains a floating-point number (not a NaN), and `b = a` is executed, then `b.myfloat == a.myfloat` is true.